# Close and Flag option enabled for self question

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

I have a small doubt..

When we ask any question, what is use of close and flag buttons?

For example :-
[image]

Here, myself only have asked a question, then what is use of putting close and flag buttons?
Either they should be disabled or invisible. As no one will go for such option, users will directly delete answer.

If this options are really use for self question person, how this can be useful?

It just a thought of making web site for friendly, rather than seeing more options.

Thanks

Comment: I've needed to get my own duplicate questions closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why flag your own question?

To request moderator action.

Anything that you cannot do yourself but moderators can do, is fair game. If you realize you asked your question on the wrong site, for example, you can flag it to request a migration.

Another reason to request moderator attention is if another user is causing problems (like vandalizing your post with repeated edits); dealing with conflicts is best left to the moderation team as well.

> Why close your own question?

There may be cases where someone points out that your question is a duplicate, or not a real question and you want to delete it, but it already has upvoted answers from other users. In such a case, you may want to close the question.

Comment: Thanks, nice information..

Answer (score 3):

You might agree with others that your question should be closed, but you can no longer delete it for example. In such a case you can vote to close it.

And if there is anything requiring the attention of a moderator, you can flag to notify them.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess delete option works everytime if we want to delete. Also, we have self questioned, so does it makes sense asking moderator to pay attention to our self question?

Comment: @Prateek The delete option does not work if your question has upvoted/accepted answers.

Comment: @RaghavSood Yes, I forgot that point..

Answer (score 3):

For flagging, you may still need to make the mods aware of an issue with the post.

For voting to close, I know for sure that it's possible for someone to want to vote to close their own post. I know, because [I have done it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13872316/237838). I posted that question, then realized it was a duplicate, so voted to close.